# How to smoothen the Parallax Scrolling with Swipe Gesture

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, gesture-recognition, parallax

I have add the Gestures Classes available from the [example](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5270) to support the Gesture rcognition.
I have 4 Sprites in the Top Layer to be moved at the Swipe Left/Right and have 3 Sprites to Swipe at the Bottom Layer.

I have the following code

```
-(id) init
{
// Some Stuff
[Gestures sharedGestures].swipeTolerance = 40;
[Gestures sharedGestures].pointResetLimit = 10;
[Gestures sharedGestures].delegate = self;
[Gestures sharedGestures].useX = NO;
[Gestures sharedGestures].useCircle = NO;
[Gestures sharedGestures].useSquare = NO;
for (int i=1; i<6; i++) 
    {
        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Howtoplay_0%d.png",i];
        topLayer[i]=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:str];
        [topLayer[i] setPosition:ccp(640/2,480/2)];
        [self addChild:topLayer[i] z:1];
        [topLayer[i] setVisible:NO];
    }
    [topLayer[1] setVisible:YES];
    [topLayer[1] setPosition:ccp(320/2,480/2)];

    for (int i=1; i<4; i++) 
    {
        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HowtoplayB_0%d.png",i];
        backLayer[i]=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:str];
        [backLayer[i] setPosition:ccp((320*i)/2,480/2)];
        [self addChild:backLayer[i] z:-1];

    }
    [backLayer[1] setPosition:ccp(320/2,480/2)];
}

-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher{
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:1 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[[Gestures sharedGestures] reset];
return TRUE;
}

-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint converted = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];
    [[Gestures sharedGestures] addPoint:converted];
}
-(void) swipeLeftComplete
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Left Complete Called");
    [self MoveLeft];

}
-(void) swipeRightComplete
{
    [self MoveRight];
}
-(void)MoveLeft
{
    [topLayer[currentTop+1] setPosition:ccp(640/2,480/2)];
    [topLayer[currentTop+1] setVisible:YES];
    [topLayer[currentTop] runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(-320/2,480/2)]];
    [topLayer[currentTop+1] runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(320/2,480/2)]];

    [topLayer[currentTop-1] setVisible:NO];
    currentTop+=1;
}
-(void) MoveRight
{
    [topLayer[currentTop-1] setVisible:YES];
    [topLayer[currentTop] setVisible:YES];
    [topLayer[currentTop] runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(-320/2,480/2)]];
    [topLayer[currentTop-1] runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(320/2,480/2)]];
    currentTop--;
}
```

I am unable to Swipe Right/Left Smoothly it gives the overlapping of the topLayer. Please Help me to smoothen the layer movement.

Any kind of Help will be Appreciated

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds similar to problems I, and others, have faced with tiling sprites and borders between them. Try adding this to the top of your init statement:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setProjection:CCDirectorProjection2D];
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it doesn't work. It moves with the gap between 2 top Layers.

Comment: @Marine Any chance you could post a screen shot of this gap? This might be difficult if it only appears during movement, but I'm not quite understanding what you're seeing vs what should be happening.